# PLT Scheme: Evaluate a string, or list of strings?

Tags: racket

If I do a:

```
(regexp-split (regexp " ") "look tom")
```

I get

```
("look" "tom")
```

Which is fine, but I can't eval that. If I try to (eval-string) it [which is inside mzlib/string], it errors out, saying that 'tom' isn't defined. I guess it's trying to run:

```
(look tom)
```

Which isn't correct either. Any tips here?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what functionality you are looking for.

Are you trying to run:

```
(look)
(tom)
```

If look and tom are defined as functions you can use something like:

```
(define (look) 1)
(define (tom) 1)

(map (lambda (s) (apply (eval (string->symbol s)) '())) '("look" "tom"))
```

Or if look and tom are variables and you want to replace them with their values:

```
(define look 1)
(define tom 1)

(map (lambda (s) (eval (string->symbol s))) '("look" "tom"))
```

If you are trying to evaluate (look tom) then:

```
(define (look arg) arg)
(define tom 'arg)

(eval (map string->symbol '("look" "tom")))
```

Also you probably would have gotten a response to your question before now if you had also tagged the post scheme.